# Internationalization of an Python application using Glade and GTK3

Tags: python, internationalization, gtk3, glade

The problem is that I cannot import gtk.glade (it's a GTK2 import). My first try was this

```
try:
    import gtk
    import gtk.glade
except:
    sys.exit(1)
import gettext
APP="pytemp"
DIR="po"
gettext.textdomain(APP)
gettext.bindtextdomain(APP, DIR)

gtk.glade.textdomain(APP)
gtk.glade.bindtextdomain(APP, DIR)
```

But this last 2 lines doesn't work with GTK3, so I don't know how I can change my code...
I want to use gettext for translate in different languages but i can't access to Glade strings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to bind a text domain to a local folder for gettext under GTK3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10094335/how-to-bind-a-text-domain-to-a-local-folder-for-gettext-under-gtk3)

Comment: Oh so sorry, I didn't see that post, thanks for the link.