# Python and PyGObject translating doesn't work

Tags: python, translation, pygobject

I'm trying to translate a Python application. So I followed the example of this answer : [How to bind a text domain to a local folder for gettext under GTK3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10094335/how-to-bind-a-text-domain-to-a-local-folder-for-gettext-under-gtk3).
This is my folders' organization :

```
.
├── mo
│   └── fr
│       └── LC_MESSAGES
│           └── myapp.mo
├── test.glade
└── test.py
```

And this is my `myapp.mo`:

```
# SOME DESCRIPTIVE TITLE.
# Copyright (C) YEAR THE PACKAGE'S COPYRIGHT HOLDER
# This file is distributed under the same license as the PACKAGE package.
# FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, YEAR.
#
#, fuzzy
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2015-09-16 18:48+0200\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"Language: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=CHARSET\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"

#: test.glade:66
msgid "Document"
msgstr "Document"

#: test.glade:30
msgid "Edit"
msgstr "Modifier"

#: test.glade:18
msgid "File"
msgstr "Fichier"

#: test.glade:42
msgid "Find"
msgstr "Trouver"

#: test.glade:54
msgid "View"
msgstr "Vue"
```

I didn't edit `test.glade` or `test.py`. But when I lunch `python3 test.py` it's still in English and not in French... Why?